# Propel "ON UPDATE" inside schema.xml

Tags: mysql, sql, orm, schema, propel

I'm attempting to insert the option "`ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`" inside column of my `schema.xml` on PROPEL ORM.

Suppose my `schema.xml` contains

```
<column name="modified" phpName="Modified" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultExpr="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" required="true"/>
```

I would like to add the *"`ON UPDATE`"* SQL statement for this column.

Actually my trick is run

```
propel diff
```

Insert "`ON UPDATE`" inside the generated-migration, obtaining

```
CHANGE `modified` `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and at the end

```
propel migrate
```

to make effective all changes.

There's a manner to insert this specification inside the *"column"* Tag, as done for *"defaultExpr..."* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add:

```
<column name="modified" phpName="Modified" type="TIMESTAMP" defaultExpr="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" required="true"/>
```